# What is macro is used to find the Android Platform in CMake?

Tags: android, cmake

In CMake file the platform checking condition not able to executing.

"I read this [article](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Write-Platform-Checks)  but i could not find the any macro to enable the android specific code in CMake file."

```
if(UNIX)
    //find this path
elseif (__ANDROID__)
    //find this path
endif()
```

Expecting result if i run on android platform it should encounter android path statement only.